# Error messages displayed within the YoutubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm embedding a youtube player within my android application.

When an error occurs while loading a youtube video with the android player, a textual message is displayed within the YoutubePlayerView.

I want to retry loading the video until a specific timeout is reached.

Is there a way to avoid that behavior (the visual notifications of errors within the YoutubePlayerView) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done via the YouTube SDK.

What you can do is this

1. Override `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener.onError` and `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener.onLoaded`
2. When an error occurs (`onError` is triggered), simultaneously hide the `YouTubePlayerView` and show a black `View` on top of it (with a loading `ProgressBar`, eventually)
3. If the video loads correctly (`onLoaded` is triggered), hide the black View and show the `YouTubePlayerView`

Comment: Thanks. 
This partially worked but the visual artefacts now remain when the network is back and the video starts (after I remove the covering view).
I have to re-initialize the player so that it works correctly.

Comment: You should not need to re-init the player. Why is that?

Comment: Hi dextor, I did that because when I call the load function in the onError, the (reload) button and the "network not available" message remain in the screen (on top of the video) even after the network is back and the playback is resumed.